# What sites use Viewstate

Tags: asp.net, webforms, viewstate

Anyone know of any significant websites using VIEWSTATE? Significant being having complex or sizeable viewstate?

I'm working on something to optimize viewstate and after an hour I can't find a single website using it. I'm just tired, and it's a google resistent term, but hoping someone can help. I have a test website that will generate it already, but I'm looking for real world use cases.

Answer (score 0):

I have used this with success. Could be an option instead of rolling your own. 
https://viewstatetodb.codeplex.com/

You can create a page with large viewstate quite easily. Perhaps a repeater with textboxes.